# Techincal Guidences of collection.allow in Meteor JS?

Tags: meteor

I need to know the **Technical Meaning of collection.allow()** in Meteor JS.i had studied meteor document but not understand properly.So Can you please explain the below the terms with use of below code.

- what is the doc?
- How to check Posts.allow() is return true/false?
- How to call the below methods like insert,update & remove when ever clicks a button?
- How to write queries to insert , update & remove using the below methods in Meteor JS?
- How to check more than one person allows to insert,update & remove queries?

Can you please give me suggestions about above things ?

```
    Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");

    Posts.allow({
      insert: function (userId, doc) {
        // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
        return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
      },
      update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        // can only change your own documents
        return doc.owner === userId;
      },
      remove: function (userId, doc) {
        // can only remove your own documents
        return doc.owner === userId;
      },
      fetch: ['owner']
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are used to validate an insert/update/delete that the client requests. If the client calls `Posts.insert(somePost)`. The server will use `Posts.allow` to validate if this can actually take place. To answer your questions directly:

```
what is the doc?
```

The `doc` in these methods is the document the client passes in. In my above example it would be `somePost`.

```
How to check Posts.allow() is return true/false?
```

Posts.allow() will check to see if a user can insert a post and return `true` if they can and `false` if they cannot (this is your responsibility). In your example there must be a valid userId and the document's owner must be the currently logged in user. Since your `doc` is a JSON object it must have an `owners` field in this example. If you always return false, then no client will ever be able to create a post. If you always return true, then any request to insert a post will be accepted.

```
How to call the below methods like insert,update & remove when ever clicks a button?
```

You actually never call these methods directly. They are called for you when the client attempts to insert/update/delete a Post.

```
How to write queries to insert, update & remove using the below methods in Meteor JS?
```

Again, you never actually call these directly, but when you do `Posts.insert(somePost)`, it will automatically attempt to validate against the `insert` allow method. If it receives a `true` the post is inserted. If it receives a `false` it will throw an exception.

```
How to check more than one person allows to insert,update & remove queries?
```

Not exactly sure what you mean by this but if you have two people logged in and they both attempt to insert a post you can validate them uniquely given the `userId` field in the methods.

---

Update:

I'll elaborate on your comment's question. The document object just has an owner property on it. The document that is passed in may look like something like this (simplified):

```
doc = {
    "name":"My Important Document",
    "description": "This is a great document.",
    "createdOn": 1394043417621,
    "owner": b8QsgX3awg7E9DMKs
}
```

So `doc.owner` would give you the document's owner's id. You can then compare it to the `userId` passed in, to see if they are the same person.

Comment: Can you Please give me suggestion about doc.owner?.@Firo